# Issue with showing and updating image in Tkinter

Tags: python, regex, image, tkinter, web-scraping

I'm able to display an image if I grab it from one location, but I need the image to update along with the related article from a website. So if you open my application tomorrow, a different image will appear. So needless to say, I'm using regular expressions but the image just won't show on the label. Here's my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
import re
from re import findall
from urllib import urlopen
import datetime
from PIL import Image
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from cStringIO import StringIO


root = Tk()
root.title("Science and Technology")
root.geometry("600x600")
main_label = Label(root, text = "Science and Technology")
main_label.pack()

all_image_height = 400
all_image_width = 400
dash = "-"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
text_area = LabelFrame(root, borderwidth = 2)
text_area.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, expand = 1, fill= BOTH)
date = Label(text_area)
date.pack()
content_t = Label(text_area)
content_t.pack()
imag = Label(text_area)
imag.pack()


def science_all():
    sw_img = 300
    sh_img = 300
    webScience = urlopen(urlScience)
    html_code = webScience.read()
    webScience.close()
    titl = findall("'name'>(.+[a-zA-Z])</title>", html_code)[0]
    date1 = str(now.day),(dash),(now.month),(dash),(now.year)
    content_title = findall('itemprop="name">(.+[a-zA-Z])</h5>',html_code)[0] 

    text_area.config(text = titl)
    date.config(text = date1)
    content_t.config(text = content_title)

    url2 = "http://www.wired.com/"
    im = urlopen(url2)
    html_code2 = im.read()
    im.close()
    global image_file
    global photo_image
    global imag
    imag2 = findall('<img src="(.*)">', html_code2)
    image_file = Image.open(StringIO(html_code2))
    photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_file)
    imag.config(image=imag2)


Science = Button(root, text="Science",
                     command = science_all)

Science.pack(side=LEFT)
urlScience = 'http://www.wired.com/'
root.mainloop()
```

It works fine when using a link for one specific image from a website but when regular expressions come into it, that's where it all gets difficult for me. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Use it to test your regular expression https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: imag.config(image=imag2) should be passed the image object, not the return from findall.

Comment: I checked my regular expression and I have the right image. I also changed (image=imag2) to (image=photo_image) but I still get an error. It still says that it cannot identify image.